# Convert kusto query to rest API query

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I need to convert kusto query written for azure log analytics to rest API query so that I can use azure functions to run the query as a scheduler.
Earlier i used to convert it in the site https://dev.loganalytics.io/apiexplorer/query  , but last few weeks, looks like azure has changed this, and im not able to convert the kusto query to rest api query.

Can anyone please help me or provide me the link were i can convert this?

Comment: can anyone provide some inputs on this please?

Comment: have you gone through this document which gives you info about Kusto query and rest api usage [Query/Management HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/request)

Answer (score 0):

- Below is the sample example to send a control command to a "Service Endpoint"

  POST https://help.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/mgmt HTTP/1.1
- And here are the Request headers and Body that to be included in Query Management.

[image]

For Complete information regarding Kusto Query and Rest API go through this [Microsoft Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/rest/request)